# msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail Invalid Recipients get stripped out automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, sql-server-2008-r2, sp-send-dbmail

Looking at the documentation on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx (And some more googling) I cannot find any information about the following behaviour:

I'm trying to send a database email on Microsoft SQL 2008R2 using the following command

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Profilename', @recipients='valid@gmail.com; unvalid_gmailcom', @body = 'Testing', @body_format = 'HTML', @subject = 'Testing';
```

The obvious problem is that unvalid_gmailcom isn't a valid e-mail address. I expected to get some sort of error or warning maybe, but SQL simply strips out the invalid address and sends the mail to the remaining (if any) recipient(s).

Is there any way to find out when SQL does this or is the only way to sanitize the code so this cannot happen?

Comment: Sanitizing the code is always a good idea... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the error, but the results (failure and success) are stored in msdb. Following views sysmail_allitems, sysmail_sentitems, sysmail_unsentitems, sysmail_faileditems are available in msdb for this purposes.

More here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191278.aspx